# Duplication a program from one PI to another

Tags: raspicam, motion

I have Motion installed on one PI and wondered if it was possible to easy duplicate the install process, with dependencies, on a another pi without either:

1) Installing and configuring it again 
 2) Removing the SD card and making a backup of the image, then duplicating the image to the second PI

I remember it was difficult to get it working with the NOIR PI-cam, and I cannot remember exactly what I did to get it to work.

```
`dpkg -l motion | grep -E "^ii" | tr -s ' ' | cut -d' ' -f3`
```

gives version:   **3.2.12-34**

Comment: A block-wise copied SD card would work just fine in another Pi. Problems may arise with the double use of credentials or e.g. when using static network configuration and attaching both devices to the same local network segment. So be sure to watch out for such things.

Comment: Is it possible just to copy a program, settings and dependies; without duplicating the entire sd card?

Comment: I don't know what you did during configuration. But the clean way would be to install the program and it's dependencies again on that new RPi (your package manager should help). Then locate the configuration files on the first RPi (refer to the documentation to find them) and copy those to the second RPi.

Comment: How can I find out dependencies of the working motion install? I did a clean install, but forgot which libraries I installed? I also would like to compaire motion versions . Im not sure how to use the package manager.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

on the source Pi just type

```
history
```

To see the list of commands that had run previously, as long as you have not entered more that a few hundred all the commands will be there.

If this is Raspbian or another Debian based dsitro you can find out what .deb packages have been installed with

```
dpkg --get-selections
```

But that is likely to be quite long.

As this is **motion** you will also want the config file that you should have created from the example one provided and stored in your own prefered location.

Comment: Unfortunately we still don't know whether it's raspbian or not and therefore whether there is dpkg or not.